# Query to show all items for every months

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables: shipped (item, qty_shipd, date_shpd) and forecast (item, qty_forecat, date_forecast) and i need something below

```
Item   Forecast   Shipped   Forecast_date   Shipped_date
item1  50         100       2018-01-01      2018-01-15
item2  0          50        -               2018-01-06
item3  100        100       2018-02-01      2018-02-05
item4  150        0         2018-02-01      -
item1  0          20        -               2018-03-15
item1  10         50        2018-04-01      2018-04-28
```

Is it possibile have something like this table?
Thanks so much

Comment: You need to show the raw data.  It is quite unclear how these are combined.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm.  This seems rather complicated.  You seem to want to combine the rows from both tables within a month, not losing any values from either one.

If so, I think this does what you want:

```
select item, max(shipped) as shipped, max(shipped_date) as shipped_date,
       max(forecast) as forecast, max(forecast_date) as forecast_date
from ((select Item, Shipped, Shipped_date, null as forecast, null as forecast_date,
              row_number() over (partition by item, year(shipped_date), month(shipped_date) order by shipped_date) as seqnum
       from shipped
      ) union all
      (select Item, NULL as Shipped, NULL as Shipped_date, null as forecast, null as forecast_date,
              row_number() over (partition by item, year(shipped_date), month(shipped_date) order by shipped_date) as seqnum
       from shipped
      )
     ) sf
group by item, year(coalesce(shipped_date, forecast_date)), 
         month(coalesce(shipped_date, forecast_date)), seqnum
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Calendar Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/30/calendar-tables-in-t-sql/) (temporary or simply permanent table).

Join the calendar table date with each shipped and forecast date using outer join. Don't forget to join forecast item with shipped item. Also handle if the data from shipped and forecast is NULL

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(f.item, s.item) AS Item, 
    c.Date, 
    ISNULL(qty_forecat,0) AS Forecast, 
    ISNULL(qty_shipd,0) AS Shipped, 
    date_forecast AS Forecast_date, 
    date_shpd AS Shipped_date
FROM 
    Calendar AS c 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN forecast AS f 
        ON c.Date=f.date_forecast 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN shipped AS s 
        ON c.Date=s.date_shpd 
        AND f.item=s.item
```